# Comparing All columns of two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Table1:

ID, F_Name, L_Name, Age, City, State, ZIP

Table2:

ID, F_Name, L_Name, Age, City, State, ZIP

I need to compare all the columns of these two tables.

What should be the SQL query?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to find the rows which are present in one table and are absent in another? Or only some columns must be compared (for example, the difference in `ID` must be ignored)? In general - use, for example, LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL.

Comment: Provide more detail what you are trying to compare, provide your table design with some data. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the SQL query to compare the columns (all columns) between two tables and write unmatched records to a new table.